# 1pixelout_audio-player.js is not found on blogs of stackexchange

Tags: bug, blog, 404-not-found

When i go to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/ i get a **404 Not Found** for the request (*analyzed by Developer Tools of Chrome*)

> https://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/plugins/podpress/players/1pixelout/1pixelout_audio-player.js

The Console also contains an error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: podpressAudioPlayer is not defined (index):49
(anonymous function) (index):49
```

The site works normally and it seems nothing is broken despite this error.

Comment: True, though can't see anything broken in the page itself.